# Observable that produces a single item per subscription - one event per handler

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

Let's say I would like to expose an observable that notifies either immediately, if an Internet connection is available right now, or if the device is not connected to the Internet the notification would be pushed out when it does become available:

```
IObservable<DateTime> InternetBecameAvailableSignalledOncePerSubscriber { get; }
```

Furthermore, there should be only one notification per subscription without requiring the subscriber to do .Take(1) or anything like that.

i.e. the client that depends on an Internet resource would use this observable to do something right now or as soon as the Internet becomes available, but would not do it more than once - there would be no more signalling to that subscriber if Internet became unavailable and available a second time..

How could this be implemented with Reactive Extensions (Rx) ?

- Please ignore the flawed notion that Internet can become available as such, think of it as google.com being reachable or whatever flavored implementation you prefer

Comment: you can do this with .Aggregate - but in this case I would recommend writting your own class/wrapper as you might want to control the subscription prozess a bit better

Comment: You can definitely do this with Rx, but when there is only one notification often an async method is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easily solved with Rx. The question is how will you know if the internet is available? Is it based on other consumers subscribing, is it based on another method (like a `Connect()` method) or some event that is being pushed to you (like a WCF Channel state changed event)?

Depending on this answer, it seems you just need to encapsulate your Take(1) and Replay(1).

```
public class IServiceClient
{
    IObservable<DateTime> LastConnnected { get; }
}

public class ServiceClient : IServiceClient, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _connection;
    private readonly IObservable<DateTime> _lastConnnected;

    public ServiceClient()
    {
        //Question 1) where does the 'Connected' sequence come from i.e. what is it that tells you that you have internet connectivity?
        //Question 2) When should the subscription be made to 'Connected'? Here I cheat and do it in the ctor, not great.
        var connected = Connected.Replay(1)
                                .Where(isConnected=>isConnected)
                                .Take(1)
                                .Select(_=>DateTime.UtcNow);

        _lastConnnected = connected;
        _connection = connected.Connect();
    }

    public IObservable<DateTime> LastConnnected{ get {return _lastConnnected; } }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This does leave you with some other questions to answer e.g. what is the thing that tells you if you have internet connectivity and what is the resource management plan for this?

**Updated code**

```
public interface IServiceClient
{
    IObservable<DateTime> LastConnnected { get; }
}

public class ServiceClient : IServiceClient, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _connection;
    private readonly IObservable<bool> _lastConnnected;

    public ServiceClient(IObservable<ConnectionState> connectedStates)
    {
        var cachedStates = connectedStates.Select(state=>state.IsConnected).Replay(1);
        _lastConnnected = cachedStates;
        _connection = cachedStates.Connect();
    }

    public IObservable<DateTime> LastConnnected
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _lastConnnected.StartWith(IsConnected())
                                  .Where(isConnected=>isConnected)
                                  .Take(1)
                                  .Select(_=>DateTime.UtcNow); 
        } 
    }

    //....

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I have a method bool IsConnected() that can be used to see if a value should be pushed immediately, and if that is false, then I have a hot IObservable<ConnectionState> that streams Disconnected and Connected states - I am not really familiar with connectable observables, so how should the code change given this source method and sequence?

Comment: Here we are saying that we want to replay 1 value so it should cache the last value it sees. However, this need to be subscribed to be able to do this. In this scenario, we "connect" to invoke the subscription and start caching values. In your case this wont do much as your sequence is already hot. Code updated